# VueJS with Webpack: imports and exports not working as expected

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, vuetify.js

I started a new Vuetify / Webpack project, and tried to implement `vue-router` after setting up a project via `vue init vuetify/webpack`.

I set up the router based on the instructions from [this tutorial](https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/vue-js-routing-with-vue-router-4c428fabb078). After some fiddling, I got it working by changing the way I imported Vue components.

In my `router/index.js` file:

```
// works for me
import Main from '../components/Main.vue'

// does NOT work; from the tutorial
import Main from '@/components/Main'
```

My question is, why do I have to import my `Main.vue` file relatively and include the `.vue extension` on the import?

---

#### My project structure:

```
-node_modules/
-public/
-src/
|-components/
||-Main.vue
|-router/
||-index.js
|-App.vue
|main.js
-index.html
-package.json
-webpack.config.js
```

#### My webpack.config.js file:

```js
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')
 
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'build.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'public': path.resolve(__dirname, './public')
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          loaders: {
          }
          // other vue-loader options go here
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          objectAssign: 'Object.assign'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.styl$/,
        loader: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'stylus-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
    }
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false
  },
  devtool: '#eval-source-map'
}
```

Comment: You probably have a different config file than the example you followed. What does your webpack config file look like?

Comment: here's the webpack.config.js: 
https://pastebin.com/kKk37a82

Comment: Did you rebuild your project?

Comment: Yes, here's the full output: https://imagebin.ca/v/3NalAP27rtgr

Comment: Can you share your config file as it currently is on pastebin again?

Comment: webpack.config.js as it is currently: https://pastebin.com/0aJRJ6cY

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145051/discussion-between-thanksd-and-evetterdrake).

Answer (score 3):

You are attempting to load a file from an [alias](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-alias) directory named `@`. But in your webpack config file, you haven't defined that alias.

Also, you are required to specify the `.vue` extension because you haven't added it to the resolvable [`extensions`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-extensions) in the `resolve` property in your config object.

In your `webpack.config.js` file, add a list of extensions to resolve and an alias called `@` which maps to your `src` directory:

```
resolve: {
  extensions: ['', '.js', '.vue'],
  alias: {
    '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

---

Edit: @evetterdrake informed me that when using `vue-cli` to set up a project with Vuetify, the `resolve` config property is positioned after the `module` property, which is different than when setting up a normal Webpack project.

Be sure to add these config options to the existing `resolve` property or it will be overwritten and ignored.